# Scheduling ruby script based on Variable time

Tags: ruby, api, email, schedule

I have a general question about scheduling scripts.

I'm faced with a challenge that I need to schedule a reminder email for X days in advance via an API using ruby. However, there is no scheduling functionality built into the API call.

So, my idea is to run a ruby script that sends the first email and at the end schedules a separate ruby script to run for X days in advance. Make sense?

The logic would look like:

```
Email.send(test@test.com)
Rubyscript.schedule(Time.now + X days)
```

Does that make sense? Basically I'm wondering how I can schedule a ruby script from a ruby script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe look into using [Delayed::Job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job)?  It might be overkill, but it's super easy...

Altering your code accordingly:

```
Email.delay(:run_at => 7.days.from_now).send('test@test.com')
```

There's also [whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever), and other [cron-like scheduling gems](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/scheduling).

Comment: Got it. I think the Delayed::Job will take care of it. Thanks for the tip.